Proof that lamps in serial don't share the voltage
Imagine two lamps in serial in a circuit with a 4V battery. Then the voltage across each lamp is 2V.
Wrong.
Lamps are resistances. But the above answer does not depend on resistance. Therefore, we can take the resistances to be infinitesimally small, and that should not change the answer. But if we do that, then clearly the voltage across two points that contain 1 (but not both) lamps is equivalent to the voltage across two points that contain neither (or both) lamps. And this voltage is 4V!

Where's the question?

You are extrapolating to infinitesimals without considering whether that extrapolation is even valid.

Are the lamps identical? If not, why would the voltage across each lamp not be different?

Nonsense. Resistance has everything to do with it. It is a simple series voltage divider circuit. If both lamps' resistance are equal and wired in series, the voltage is equally divided. You do not need a calculator to figure the math out. If Lamp 1 resistance = 1 Ohm and lamp 2 resistance = 3 ohms wired in series with a 4-volt battery, the voltage drop is 1 and 3 volts, respectively, with 1 amp of current flowing, 4-finger math.

You say "resistance has everything to do with it" but then say "if both lamps' resistance are equal and wired in series, the voltage is equally divided" --- at no point in this last sentence did you specify the resistance. Good job, you just made my point. Now take that non-specified but equal resistance to be infinitely small.

@ammo45 Did you actually attempt to physically measure the voltage across two identical lamps in series? You'll find the voltages to be approximately equal.

@ammo45 If the resistance of both lamps is 0Ω, the voltage across both will be 0V, so still identical.

No, the battery is 4V. The voltage across both will be 4V, which is not "shared", i.e not half.

Circuit analysis is an approximation, used to make circuit design easier.  If you're asking about a real-world situation, zero or infinitesimally small resistances don't exist.  Quantum effects may dominate.  If you're talking about "ideal" elements and analysis then the voltage across the two bulbs of equal resistance will be the same 2 V as the resistance approaches zero.  The point where they reach zero is a singularity with where quantities are undefined or infinite. (e.g. infinite current).

@ammo45 at no point in this last sentence did you specify the resistance ... there is no need to specify the absolute value of the two resistances, only the ratio of the two resistances

@ammo45 The voltage across two 0Ω resistances cannot be 4V, period. A real voltage source will be dragged down to 0V at the point where it connects to the lamps. An ideal voltage source in series with an ideal 0Ω resistance is impossible. The fact remains, that the voltage across two identical resistances (whether zero or non-zero) is equal.
